# How to use hook_views to filter data?

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom entity with (among others) a field defined this way:

```
$fields['datedistribution'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')  
  ->setLabel(t('Date distribution'))  
  ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'date')  
  ->setDefaultValue(array(0 => array(  
    'default_date_type' => 'now',  
    'default_date' => 'now',  
  )))  
 ...
```

I created a View on this custom entity displaying (among others) this 'datedistribution' field.
When I try and to use it as a filter criterion, I don't have condition I expect to have for a date (I'd like to be able to select with this field being greater than today, for example):
[image]
So, I search in the direction of hook_views to filter my data before running my View.
So far, no idea of what hook I should use and how to code it.
Could someone help on that?

Comment: see this issue, the solution is in the last comment https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2489476#comment-12269159

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how to use that...
I put this in getViewsData() but I couldn't see any difference...
`    $data['distribution_date']['datedistribution__value']['filter'] = [`
`            'field' => 'datedistribution__value',`
`            'table' => 'distribution_date',`
            'id' => 'datetime',
            'field_name' => 'datedistribution',
            'entity_type' => 'distribution_date',
            'allow empty' => TRUE,
            ];
        return $data;
      }
}`

Comment: You have to extend EntityViewsData, put getViewsData() in it and first get the data from the parent `$data = parent::getViewsData();` Point the entity handler to the new class `"views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData"` (replace this class with the new one)

Comment: I finally made it work!
Using #13 of [https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2489476#comment-12269159](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2489476#comment-12269159) as an example